# Bash script to remove line breaks?

Tags: bash

I need a script that inputs a file and echos its contents with linebreaks removed - "word wrapped" so to speak.

I've tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
find $HOME '$1' | while read line; do echo "${line}"; done
```

but it just returns nothing.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
echo $(cat $1)
```

Comment: Glad I could help you out finding one-out-of-many-ways-to-get-there, but try Googling a bit more next time. [This](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/sed-how-do-you-replace-end-of-line-with-a-space-637013/) is what I got as a second result popping up using the keywords ``bash``, ``line``, ``end``, ``remove``.

Comment: @gertvdijk years have passed, and this question is what I got as a first result popping up using similar keywords now :)

Comment: non-script/cmdline way is `echo \`cat some_file.ext\``

Comment: No idea why this answer got so many upvotes. It squeezes multiple spaces to a single one, converts tabs to spaces, neither of which OP asked for. And it consumes a lot of memory in case of a large input file. Let alone edge cases like if the file's contents begins with `-n` or `-e` which is interpreted by `echo` as an option. The answers using `tr` are much better.

Answer (score 11):

I found this relevant answer in stackoverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n

The quickest way appears to be using tr:

```
tr '\n' ' ' </your/file
```

or for your example:

```
cat `find $HOME '$1"` | tr '\n' ' '
```

To learn more about the `tr` command do, of course, `man tr`.

The stackoverflow anser contains ways to do this with sed (would have been my first choice, but sed is very line-oriented and getting it to not interpret line breaks as field delimiters is arcane) and a way using read and bash, close to your initial approach.

Answer (score 1):

## Answer

```bash
tr -d `\n` </your/file
```

## Explanation

What `tr` does:

```
Usage: tr [OPTION]... SET1 [SET2]

Translate, squeeze, and/or delete characters from standard input,
writing to standard output.
```

Option `-d`:

```
  -d, --delete            delete characters in SET1, do not translate
```